# Ansible playbook error

Tags: ansible

I am testing with ansible, what I'm trying to do is install apache2 on another ubuntu server, I already have the group "test" defined with 1 ip. but what happens is that ansible throws me some errors when executing it, I've searched a lot of sites and a lot of people have had this issue, but on different situations and I amd starting to get frustrated with it. Can somebody help me?

Ansible Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: test
  sudo: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Check if Im sudo
      command: echo $USER

    - name: install packages
      apt: name:apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest
      notify: start apache2

  handlers:
    - name: start apache2
      service: name=apache2 state=started
```

STDOUT

```
root@ip-172-31-35-33:/etc/ansible/example# ansible-playbook example.yml

PLAY [test] *******************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [172.31.36.176]

TASK: [Check if Im sudo] ******************************************************
changed: [172.31.36.176]

TASK: [install packages] ******************************************************
failed: [172.31.36.176] => {"failed": true}
msg: this module requires key=value arguments (['name:apache2', 'update_cache=yes', 'state=latest'])

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/example.retry

172.31.36.176              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

BTW, the host is reachable, I can ssh into it, even with ansible, this is the proof

```
root@ip-172-31-35-33:/etc/ansible/example# ansible -m shell -a "ifconfig | grep 'inet addr'" test
172.31.36.176 | success | rc=0 >>
          inet addr:172.31.36.176  Bcast:172.31.47.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

another thing is that I'm able to install apache2 by hand on the other server, BUT IT IS NOT INSTALLED BECAUSE I WANT TO INSTALL IT USING ANSIBLE

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a colon where an equal is needed. You need to change the `name:apache2` to `name=apache2`.

Answer (score 3):

Within an individual task, Ansible requires you to make the choice between standard YAML syntax and their own parsed version with equals signs.  In this task, you are mixing the two:

```
- name: install packages
  apt: name:apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest
  notify: start apache2
```

This could be either written:

```
- name: install packages
  apt: 
    name: apache2 
    update_cache: yes
    state: latest
  notify: start apache2
```

Or:

```
- name: install packages
  apt: name=apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest
  notify: start apache2
```

YAML also allows for using bracket and comma syntax to allow you to specify your key-value information on the same line:

```
- name: install packages
  apt: {name: apache2, update_cache: yes, state: latest}
  notify: start apache2
```

Any of these are valid.